# cp -r versus -R flag

Tags: bash, flags, cp

I am using the cp command in a bash script for data management purposes where I need directories to be recursively copied from one location to another. As it is very important that my script would give me the correct behavior I am double checking all the commands and flags that I am using. To this extend I was reading the Man page of the `cp` command where the recursive copying options are described as follows:

**-r:      copy recursively, non-directories as files**

**-R, --recursive:    copy directories recursively**

As I understand, recursive copying means that the content of a directory and all its subdirectories are copied as well. Does -R not copy subdirectories and content? What is the difference between both options?

I have used -r in previous scripts which always worked as intended, but I'm curious to the difference as -R might be more appropriate in future cases.

Comment: What version of `cp` are you using? BSD `cp` doesn't support `-r` at all, and `-r` and `-R` are synonyms in GNU `cp`. (That said, this would be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com, as it is about the usage of a pre-existing command-line tool.)

Comment: Check this out, maybe it can help: https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/aix/7.2?topic=c-cp-command

Answer (score 1):

Based on man page both option does the same operation.

```
   -R, -r, --recursive
              copy directories recursively
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess they are the same after all! I got my info from https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html